# Why do i get the error message 'cube either does not exist or has not been processed. '

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, cube

The SQL cube I was working on got decommissioned to a new cube, so I changed my connection string to point to the new cube. I keep getting the error `cube either does not exist or has not been processed.`

In the mdx query, I changed the `select` statement to select from the old cube and to the new one. I was given dev and USER roles in SQL and under properties I have read, write and full control permissions.

I can pull reports from the new cube without a problem in Excel, but in my ASP.NET application I keep getting the error.
I have tried searching for related issues, but no luck. Please if anyone has experienced in this problem, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a code example to reproduce your problem, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what the problem was,the cube i was pointing/rather selecting the Measures from in SQL has a different name other than the name of the cube itself,which is model.

i.e  FROM
     [Model]
istead of:
       FROM
       [cubeName]